# set header in .htaccess not working if REQUEST_URI contains a word

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, headers

I need to set some headers if `REQUEST_URI` contains the "compile" word.

My uri is:

```
http://myurl/compile/123456/123456?token=myvalue
```

This is the code in the .htaccess that DOES NOT work:

```
Header always set MyHeaderCompile myvalue "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /compile/"
```

This line does not set MyHeaderCompile header.

If I change the line with this:

```
Header always set MyHeaderCompile myvalue "expr=%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /token/"
```

It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI`.

Thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/57379503/4641073 I read that `REQUEST_URI` can be changed from other directives, instead `THE_REQUEST` never changes.

The line that works is this:

```
Header always set MyHeaderCompile myvalue "expr=%{THE_REQUEST} =~ /compile/"
```

Comment: I would imagine a request such as `/compile/123456/123456` requires _rewriting_ - this will change the value of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable.